# subclass as template template argument of template base class, which in turn is a subclass function parameter

Tags: c++, c++03, template-templates

The following code

```
template<template<typename, typename> class T, typename EKeyType, typename EValueType>
class Baseclass
{
};

template<typename EKeyType, typename EValueType>
class Derived : public Baseclass<Derived, EKeyType, EValueType>
{
public:
    void foo(const Baseclass<Derived, EKeyType, EValueType>& param){}
};
```

results in the following compilation errors:

```
MSVC 14: error C3200: 'Derived<EKeyType,EValueType>': invalid template argument for template parameter 'T', expected a class template
clang 3.0.0: error: template argument for template template parameter must be a class template.
```

However `Derived` **is** a class template.

Everything compiles fine when I change the code to the following:

```
template<template<typename, typename> class T, typename EKeyType, typename EValueType>
class Baseclass
{
};

template<typename EKeyType, typename EValueType> class Derived;

template<typename EKeyType, typename EValueType>
class Derived2 : public Baseclass<Derived, EKeyType, EValueType>
{
public:
    void foo(const Baseclass<Derived, EKeyType, EValueType>& param){}
};
```

which indicates that the error message is misleading.

What is wrong with the first code?

How can I have a template subclass inherit from a template base class, with the subclass being a template template argument of the base class and also have a member function in the subclass which takes a reference to this base class as parameter?

Comment: Which version of clang are you using and which flags? I fail to reproduce this problem: https://godbolt.org/z/fl9aES

Comment: @MichaelKenzel:
I have just checked with various versions of clang and I can reproduce it on godbolt with clang versions older than 5.0.0, but I can not reproduce it with version 5.0.0 and newer versions of clang.

Comment: @MichaelKenzel It's critical for reproduction to have the foo function in the repro-code. It is missing in your link.

Comment: Ah, indeed, sry, my mistake. You already have your answer now below anyways…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first snippet is accepted by GCC and Clang. See [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cc471805b96780ea).

I seem to recall that MSVC has a bug where it considers `Derived` to refer to the injected class name, rather than the template name. However, the standard is quite clear that when the name of the enclosing class is used as an argument to a template template parameter, it should be interpreted as a template ([[temp.local]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.local#1)), so your code is fine.

It appears that the old version of Clang you are using might have the same bug.

As a workaround, you can write `::Derived` to force it to find the template name, not the injected class name.

Comment: You are correct. ::Derived makes the reprocase work and MostInnerNamespace::Derived accordingly fixes the issue when Derived is located inside one or multiple namespaces.
I can reproduce the problem on godbolt with clang versions older than 5.0.0, but I can not reproduce it with version 5.0.0 and newer versions of clang, so your assumptions regarding older versions of clang are correct.